# Como alterar um form dinamicamente?

Tags: django, formulário, django-2.0

Eu tenho dois modelos, `Empresa` e `Funcionario`. Eu gostaria que quando o usuário selecionasse a empresa os funcionários fosse setados dinamicamente no form de funcionário pois ambos os forms serão mostrados na mesma página. Então inicialmente na página eu tenho o form para selecionar a empresa e imediatamente após a seleção os dados dos funcionários ligados a empresa aparecem ao usuário.

Fiz os forms da seguinte maneira :

```
class Form_empresa(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Empresa
        fields = ['nome']


class Form_funcionario(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Funcionario
        fields = ['nome']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Form_funcionario, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['nome'].queryset = Funcionario.objects.filter(empresa = Form_empresa.cleaned_data.get('nome'))
```

Mas recebo o seguinte erro :

```
'Form_empresa' object has no attribute 'get'
```

É possível alterar um form imediatamente quando o outro for alterado (na mesma página) sem fazer o submit no Django ?

Comment: Sim, fazes um request com ajax, passas o id da form e só envia para o servidor os atributos desse form no servidor consegues ler todos com o request.POST , contudo, deixas de ter a validação da form.isvalid().